# RTC Difference between modified & lastChangeDate of a Changeset

Tags: version-control, rtc, changeset, rational-team-concert

I was going through the attributes of a changeset and I am having doubt in these 2 attributes :

**lastChangeDate :** changeset last modified date until the changeset is not marked as 'Complete'.
**modifed  :** if we make any changes to a changeset even after delivering a changeset. I found that we can modify a changeset comment even If I have delivered it, that changes the modified attribute of the changeset.

Am I correct ? If a changeset comment can be modified then what other attributes we can modify in a changet , once we have delivered it , which modify modified date attribute of it ?

Also I can't find any official documentation which explains them .